# Is there a design pattern that can help configuring commands on a generic display?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a display object that displays a list of Users and provides a menu for acting on that list - adding new users, adding them to groups, deleting them, etc.  Right now the display configures its own menu, so it can add a menu command like `doCreateNewUsers()`.  Unfortunately, this means that every instance of the display always has the "create new" option.

I want to configure the menu differently for different instances of the display - in the "Users" tab, it should include the "create new" option, and in the "Groups" tab, it shouldn't.  My first thought was to externalize the menu, so that I could configure it differently.  The problem is that then I lose the ability to call the private `doCreateNewUsers()` function!

Is there a design pattern for this situation?  I don't like the idea of making `doCreateNewUsers` public because it shows a dialog that shouldn't be triggered by external classes.  I could make the display abstract, so that I could define the menu in anonymous subclasses, but that kind of messes up the way I reuse widgets right now - I'd like to configure the menu after the display has been created and initialized.  I'm hoping there's some industry-standard way of dealing with this!

Comment: could you post some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you could possibly use the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The display can configure its own menu but only if the action can be encapsulated in the command associated with the menu item.  Once you set it up like that then you can add and remove items from the menu and they won't need access to the private methods, as they will have access to the command that is responsible for the action.

I think the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is your friend here.

Once you have the command objects you can use those to create the menu items and provide the methods to execute the actual commands.

If you are just adding a list of `User` objects the passing the command objects might make more sense.  If you are passing an object which represents a collection of users the it might make sense to add a method to expose the command objects.  If this is the case then you should probably make your objects implement an interface to give access to the command objects, something like:

```
public ICommandProvider
{
    ICollection<ICommand> GetCommands();
}
```

then a command could be:

```
public ICommand
{
     String GetMenuText();
     void Execute();  
}
```

Having the object that is being displayed responsible for returning the commands makes it easy to have the commands have a reference to the thing being displayed so they can modify it (add elements or remove elements for example).
obviously the exact details will depend on your situation, but something like that should allow you to configure your display's menu options without your display needing to know about the details of what is being done.  You'll probably need to refresh the display after a command.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  The trouble is that I want to access a private method of the display inside `Execute()`, and an `ICommand` won't have access to it.

Comment: @Riley why not make the contents of the private method what is in the `Execute()` method?  If you want to share it amongst many commands then have then all share a base class, or put the method on another class and let the command instances have an instance of that class.  By encapsulating the action in a command you make it simple to have other options like undo/redo (add an unexecute to the command an queue them) or to have multiple ways of launching a command (toolbar buttons as well as menus for example)

Comment: What is it about the private method that means you need access to it?